What is the reason the AC FAN or SYS is one of the first things checked on the A320 family?
The following sentence is focused on A320 Family because I don’t know what happens on all Airbus aircraft:
Watching some video and flying in some simulator (like MSFS2020), when you push the BAT button, all lights in the cockpit and the screen will turn on, but after few seconds you can hear the sound of some vent, which actually blows air inside cockpit (I think).
My question is: Why does this happened? Why the AC FAN or SYS is one of the first things checked on plane? And if it is (I mean is really AC SYS TEST) what will happen if the test go in fault?

There is no particular check for AC in A320. If ventilation shuts down during cockpit preparations when batteries are switched off it means you don’t have AC power (EXT ground power or APU). The battery off/on check is there to check battery bus charging relays.
